Virtual Users appearance with k6 in my website interface
I am using big blue button in my website, I am using k6 to perform load testing, the output of my code is showing success and that both student and moderator joined the conference successfully, but when I logged the url and entered manually, I saw no user entered in the conference.

There is really not enough detail in your question
